# Can you use loc to select a range of columns plus a column outside of the range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I want to select a range of columns from a dataframe: Call them 'column_1' through 'column_60'. I know I could use loc like this:
`df.loc[:, 'column_1':'column_60']`
That will give me all rows in columns 1-60.

But what if I wanted that range of columns plus 'column_81'. This *doesn't* work:
`df.loc[:, 'column_1':'column_60', 'column_81']`

It throws a "Too many indexers" error. 
Is there another way to state this using loc? Or is loc even the best function to use in this case?

Many thanks.

Comment: I stumbled over the same issue and wondered why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
df.loc[:, [f'column_{i}' for i in range(1, 61)] + ['column_81']]
```

or

```
df.reindex([f'column_{i}' for i in range(1, 61)] + ['column_81'], axis=1)
```

if you want to fill missing columns, if there are, with default `NaN` values.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I used "column_1", etc just as an example of column labels in a database. My real database column labels don't end in integers. Anyway, when I tested your solution on a dummy database, Python threw this at me:
`FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike`

Comment: Thanks, updated with `reindex`. Try to clarify in the question about column names you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.concat():

`pd.concat([df.loc[:,'column_1':'columns_60'],df.loc[:,'column_81']],axis=1)`

Comment: `pd.concat` to select a subset of columns seems overkill for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.r_` to combine ranges with scalars. The only complication is you need to use `pd.DataFrame.iloc` instead, but this can be facilitated via `df.columns.get_loc`.

Here's a demo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column'+str(i) for i in range(1, 82)])

colidx = df.columns.get_loc

res = df.iloc[:, np.r_[colidx('column1'):colidx('column5'), colidx('column80')]]

print(res.columns)

Index(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column80'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy concatenate funciton. Assuming you know the order of columns you can use:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns[np.concatenate([np.arange(1,60),np.array(81)],axis=None)]]
```

This gives you columns 1:60 plus column 81 from your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Well. After briefly going through pandas API, I guess there is no official realization for this specific purpose. So here are my proposed solutions. The basic intuition is to resemble a new indexer list.

## Easy to Remember Solution

```py
yvar = ['ln_ret_w']
xvar = df.loc[:, "size_mcap_r":"vol_beta2_r"].columns.tolist()

var = yvar + xvar
tmp = df[var].copy()
```

However, this method involves slicing `df` and thus creating a copy of `df`. Moreover, as shown below, it will be too slow if `df` is too large.

## Resource Saving Solution

```py
y_idx = df.columns.get_loc("ln_ret_w")
x_idx1 = df.columns.get_loc("size_mcap_r")
x_idx2 = df.columns.get_loc("vol_beta2_r")

idx = [y_idx] + list(range(x_idx1, x_idx2 + 1))  # Remember to add one for x_idx2
tmp = df.iloc[:, idx].copy()
```

This solution only operates `df.columns`, so it uses fewer resources in any circumstance.

My tests on a 100 million rows dataset confirm my conjecture. Solution 2 takes literally no time for datasets of any size. You can take these two codes according to your application scenario.

[image]